# Django variable inside static tag?

Tags: html, django

This is part of index.html:

```
    {% for listing in active_listings %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ listing.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ listing.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ listing.bid }}$</td>
            {% if listing.image %}
            <td>{{ listing.image }}</td>
            <td><img src="{% static 'auctions/'|add:listing.image %}" alt="photo"></td> 
            <!-- Here !!! -->
            {% else %} 
            <td>No photo.</td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
```

This is the corresponding views.py:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "active_listings": Listing.objects.filter(active=True),
    })
```

And that is my Listing Model in models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = [
        ('BO', 'Books'),
        ('TO', 'Toys'),
        ('EL', 'Electronics'),
        ('FA', 'Fashion'),
        ('HO', 'Home'),
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    bid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORIES, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Why can't I **add** the variable **listing.image** in the static tag???

It gives me: `"GET /static/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1634`.

What I want to have is `/static/auctions/foo.jpeg`, if `listing.image = 'foo.jpeg'`. How can I do this?

Comment: This is the right way : `{{ listing.image.url }}`

Comment: Yep, this works!:D